# Recovering system with HDD crash and re installing GRUB

Tags: linux, system-installation, grub2

Recently i  hard disk crash in my system.  To recover from that disaster below are the steps i followed

1. Has a master backup created using FSARCHIVER
2. In a new hard disk created required partitions

**Partition Info**

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      2097kB  271MB   268MB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      273MB   2420MB  2147MB  primary   linux-swap(v1)
 3      2422MB  23.9GB  21.5GB  primary   ext4
 4      23.9GB  320GB   296GB   extended
 5      23.9GB  77.6GB  53.7GB  logical   ext4
 6      77.6GB  320GB   242GB   logical   ext4
```

3. Booted system using GRML USB boot.
4. Restored FS using fsarchiver.

`fsarchiver restfs master.fsa id=0,dest=/dev/sda1 id=1,dest=/dev/sda3 id=2,dest=/dev/sdb5 id=3,dest=/dev/sda6`

5. I tried to install GRUB using following command, But the sytem did not boot:

`grub-install --target=i386-pc --root-directory=/mnt/ --recheck --debug /dev/sda`

I tried `/mnt` mounted in `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda5`.

I'm worried whether the GRUB method i am using is correct

**FSTAB info**

```
    proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
    # / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
    UUID=9e890f7b-dda0-41e2-9a38-fc409212b9b1 /               ext4    rw,data=journal,journal_checksum 0 1
    # /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
    UUID=213cc4e2-ead2-4be0-81d5-104b4ee525b0 /boot           ext4    ro       0       2
    # /opt was on /dev/sda6 during installation
    UUID=2df2a103-0cd3-4d0c-bc35-5f9d0b2104ac /opt            ext4    rw,data=journal,journal_checksum 0 1
    # /usr was on /dev/sda3 during installation
    UUID=6c6bfee0-bfda-4b45-ba2d-63d0d38cd920 /usr            ext4    defaults        0       2
    # swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
    UUID=ac842cd1-9655-4890-9409-0e9c1d8ed58e none            swap    sw              0       0
    /dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

Request guidance in addressing issue

Comment: Shouldn't the `grub` option be `--boot-directory=/mnt`? You've used `--root-directory`.

Comment: @garethTheRed a: u can post that as an answer, it worked ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--root-directory` option was used on the older Grub 0.97 - it's not used on version 2, which most distros use these days.

The option you need is `--boot-directory`.  From the man page:

> ```
>    --boot-directory=DIR
>           install  GRUB images under the directory DIR/grub instead of the
>           boot/grub directory
> ```

A Google search for `man grub-install` brings up the [old version](http://linux.die.net/man/8/grub-install) at the top of the list unfortunately.

Searching for `man grub2-install` returns a better [man page](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/8/grub2-install.htm).